# Subview Orientation Different from Parent Orientation

Tags: iphone, ios

My Parent View is in Portrait Mode, but i want my next View to be in Landscape Mode. But i'm unable to achieve this. For making the Next View in Landscape Mode i have to give support to my Parent View as Landscape too which i don't want. Any Suggestions????
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your next view, call

```
[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES]
```

to set it in landscape orientation.

Comment: I had tried that out but i m not able to achieve the above requirement, i want to restrict my parent view from giving it a Landscape orientation, but by doing so i m unable to change my next's view orientation to Landscape.

Comment: Have you implement - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in  your child controller to allow landscape orientation?